# Make a div with scrollbars resizable?

Tags: jquery, css

I have an extremely large table in a div with overflow set to auto, in order to have scrollbars that allows the whole table to be seen.  I would also like this div to be resizable using jquery's resizable function.  Is this possible?

I have tried `$("#driverschedule").resizable()` and it gets marked with the resizable class, but I can't seem to grab it anywhere.  I have also tried using `resizable({handles:'s'})` to be able to just grab the very bottom of the div, but this has no effect either...

Cross-browser compatibility is not a concern, this is for an internal app, and I've got control over which browsers will be used... I'm leaning towards chrome (if that matters).

Thanks!

Comment: [Can you make a jsFiddle with your markup?](http://jsfiddle.net/9zUaJ/) because that bare-bones works fine.

Comment: Have you referenced jQuery UI? Do you have any errors in your browsers console window?

Comment: @DaveHogan Yes, I've refrenced jqueryui, I've got other resizable divs on the page.  And no console errors.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, thanks for showing that it works bare bones, that gives me hope!  I'll see if I can reproduce my problem in a fiddle and get it posted.

Answer (score 0):

Hello css has a realizable option so if you wanted something resized use this but I believe you have to have a overflow of auto not 100% sure though

```
  resize:both; or
  resize:horizontal;
  resize:vertical;
```